# what are the steps to simplifying this (a+b)(a+!b)=a

Tags: boolean, algebra

what are the steps to simplifying this (a+b)(a+!b)=a

Comment: I Belive your question would be more appropriate here : http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: can you give more information?..not clear for me.

Comment: Is this better suited for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/? or math.stackexchange.com

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  You simplify *expressions*, not *equations*.

Comment: Your question does not have anything directly to do with programming.  It might just be me, but I don't understand how 'a plus not b' can work.  Or am I missing the meaning of '!'?

Comment: @Nemeth: math.stackexchange.com is not for basic questions like this.

Comment: @Greg: it's Boolean algebra, + means OR, . means AND, ! means NOT. When there is no operator it's an implied AND.

Answer (score 1):

```
  (a + b).(a + !b)

= a.(b + !b)          ; distributivity [1]

= a.1                 ; complements [1]

= a
```

1. See [Wikipedia page on Boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_%28logic%29)

Comment: You definitely need to expand on how you got from the first line to the second line...

Comment: @Oli: OK - it's just the law of distributivity but I'll comment it.